# reactjs build with routes blank page

Tags: reactjs

I have `reactjs` app, it's my first time that want to deploy/build my app, I know it's simply can do:

`npm run build`

I used this on a very simple react app before, it work fine, but now I want to deploy my react app that use `react-router-dom`, after I run `npm run build`, `index.html` is blank, it's okay maybe, because I don't have a route for home page, for example one of my page in develop mode:

```
    <Switch>
...
        <Route exact path='/User/Login' component={Login}></Route>
...
    </Switch>
```

> /User/Login

How can I access this page after deploy? I am super newbie to reactjs, I don't know how to handle this, many search, but can't find anything useful in my native language.

---

Packages.json

```
  "name": "sample",
  "homepage": "http://example.com/react/",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
```

Comment: Use the same component for both index route and login route
<Route exact path='/' component={Login}></Route>

Comment: Have you deployed the build dist on server ?

Comment: @VikashDhiman Okay, in develop mode it run login as home page `localhost:3000`, but after deploy, it's still blank page

Comment: @Rahul I just build in my local machine (windows), then upload `build` folder contents to a folder in my server

Comment: @tourtravel which server?

Comment: @Rahul my server is centos 7, linux, I just upload in `public_html/react`

Comment: have you tried this http://example.com/react/User/Login ??

Comment: @tourtravel react app needs a node.js server to work, if you still need to work on linux server then you can create static react apps using Gatsby.

Comment: @PrakashKarena of course, it's blank page, with no errors in console

Comment: it's working on localhost right ???

Comment: @Rahul I don't know which one should I use?, I use laravel api as back-end, now in this case, should use node.js server? or can go with Gatsby?

Comment: @PrakashKarena yes, `localhost:3000/User/Login` work fine

Comment: @tourtravel Gatsby can be used to create static websites. [Learn more](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/)
If you website is dynamic, frequent server side request to fetch and post data, then you need a node server to host your react app. [Learn more](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/)

Comment: @Rahul thanks for information. I going to try install node in my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React App needs a node server to be hosted.
If you want to host on linux/Ubuntu server then you will need to install node.js from NVM[Full Tutorial](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/11/18/react-nodejs-on-aws-how-to-deploy-a-mern-stack-app-to-amazon-ec2) or you can go for [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/) to create static react apps.

You can host your react app on [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/deploy-react-app-cicd-amplify/)/[Heroku](http://heroku.com/) etc.

If you are deploying react build for learning purpose only then you can use static server locally:
`npm i serve -g`
`serve -s build`

Comment: After your information, I noticed should use node.js server, but something is unclear for me here: Can I install node.js in my centos/linux server? I mean can I use my current server for this?

Comment: If you have dedicated hosting or your own server you can install node.js in it, else if shared hosting then can't.

Comment: I would suggest you to go for AWS, deployment link is given in answer. Else if you are deploying for just learning pupose then you can serve your react build on static server locally.